# Transluscent StatusBar with a AppBarLayout and Toolbar

Tags: android

How to have a good `Toolbar` when using the `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` flag ?

I tried to add almost every combinaison of `fitSystemWindow` to my view hierarchy but none is working !

Here is my layout with the best result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="fr.pdegand.fullscreentoolbar.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:title="Test"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <View
                android:background="#FF00FF"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <View
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: layout result]

But it has 2 problems : first, the Coordinator is using the `colorPrimaryDark` to fill the gap of the status bar and when the view is fully scrolled, the Toolbar doesnt disapear totally at the top of the screen.

[image: fully scrolled]

The best result would be that the Toolbar itself stretch it's top to fill the gap so that the color behind the status bar would always match the color of the toolbar (my toolbar actually have dynamic coloring in my real app) and when the view is fully scrolled the toolbar should totally disappear at the top. And if possible without code. I know I could add some `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` and manually handle the insets but I'm looking for a more generic solution that could be applied to all my screens.

Thank you for the help.